# Webview css3 animation not working properly

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview, css-animations

In my app I use CSS3 animation in webview. All animations work properly but when I change top and scale animation same time page flickers annoyingly. I open the hmtl in Chrome browser , it worked also properlery.

CSS Code

```
  .container { 
            position: relative;
        -webkit-perspective: 1000;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-animation: animationFrames ease-in 5s;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -webkit-transform-origin: ;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/  
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); 
 }
@-webkit-keyframes animationFrames {
  0% {
    left:0px;
    top:0px; 
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }

  100%{
      top:-1052px; 
    left:45px;
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(4.0) scaleY(4.0);
  }
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="leftDoor" src="leftDoor.png" style="position:absolute;"/>
    <img id="rightDoor" src="rightDoor.png"style="position:absolute;" />
    <img id="bak" src="background.png"  style="position:absolute;" />
    <p id="textOf" onclick="openDoors()">Giriş</p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function openDoors(){  
        $("#leftDoor").toggleClass("leftDoor");
        $("#rightDoor").toggleClass("rightDoor");
        $("#background").toggleClass("background");
        $("#container").toggleClass("container");
    }
```

Android webview settings

```
webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true); 
        webview.addJavascriptInterface(new ReaderJavascriptHandler(this), "OkutusJS");

        webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.OFF);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);

        webview.setScrollBarStyle(CustomWebview.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

        // webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);

        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);

        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webview.setOnTouchListener(new WebviewOnTouch(readPager,pageGestureDetector)); 

        // webview.getSettings().setNeedInitialFocus(false);
        webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webview.setInitialScale(1);

        webview.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // return true;
                return false; 
            }
        });
```

The video of problem is  http://youtu.be/ihq0-4egDHs ,

Complete html page  http://cembora.com/sample.html

NOTE: My application is hardware accelerated;

Comment: unrelated but `webview.setInitialScale(1);` is wrong, scale is in percent here so should be 100.